# Do web browsers store information in forms while processing is happening?

Tags: browser

Im creating an application and i want to know whether or not the browser will store the information in the fields if an error occurs so i can just send the browser back or should i store everything in a session and then place things back as they were with the session? I am developing my application in JSP and Servlets.

Thanks in Advance

Dean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes they do, but generally they don't -- you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: Ok then i will implement it myself in my application.